# css issue table design

Tags: html, css, angular, html-table

*please can you help me to fix the design to make data more clear ,i will be very grateful if you help me ,thanks for your answer in advance*

**this is my css file**

```
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  table-layout: fixed;
  overflow: hidden;

  }
```

**this is my html file**

```
         <div class="col-md-12">
           <div class="table-wrap">
             <table class="table table-striped" >
               <thead>
                 <tr>
                   <th class="odd" colspan="4">id</th>
                   <th class="odd" colspan="4">name</th>

                   <th *ngIf="isAdmin()" class="odd" colspan="4"> password</th>
                   <th class="odd" colspan="4">role</th>
                   <th class="odd" colspan="4"class="corner wideRow">email</th>

                 </tr>
               </thead>
               <tbody>

                 <tr *ngFor="let el of users | paginate: { itemsPerPage: 2, currentPage: p }">


                 <th class="odd" colspan="4"  ></th>
                 <td class="odd" colspan="4" >{{el.id}} </td>
                             <td class="odd" colspan="4" >{{el.username}}</td>

                             <td *ngIf="isAdmin()" class="odd" colspan="4">{{el.password}}</td>
                 <td class="odd" colspan="4" >{{el.role}}</td>
                             <td class="odd" colspan="4" >{{el.email}}</td>



                           <td  class="odd" colspan="4"> 
                 <tr>
                   <a *ngIf="isAdmin()"
                   class="btn btn-danger" (click) = "deleteUser(el.id)" >Delete</a>

                   <a *ngIf="isAdmin()" class="btn btn-success" data-original-title="Edit">Edit</a> 

                                </tr>       
 </td>
                          
                           
                         </tbody>
                       </table>
             </div>
             </div>

       </div>
       <pagination-controls (pageChange)="p = $event"></pagination-controls>
```

**this the result ,it's not clear and i didn't khnow how to fixed it**
[image: this is the result]

**when i add in css**`table td { word-break: break-all;`
}**
the result
[result 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q1lcW.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.) Having  `colspan="4"` in *each*  cell does not make any sense.

2.) The first (empty) `th` element in the `tbody` rows causes the misaligning you wrote about. Erase that to have IDs under the "id" header, names under the "name" header etc.

3.) You need an additional `th` cell in the header row (at the end) to have the same amount of cells as in the rows below it (above the cells with the nested tables which contain the two buttons).

```css
.table-striped {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table td {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="odd">id</th>
      <th class="odd">name</th>
      <th *ngIf="isAdmin()" class="odd"> password</th>
      <th class="odd">role</th>
      <th class="odd">email</th>
      <th class="odd"></th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let el of users | paginate: { itemsPerPage: 2, currentPage: p }">
      <td class="odd">{{el.id}} </td>
      <td class="odd">{{el.username}}</td>
      <td *ngIf="isAdmin()" class="odd">{{el.password}}</td>
      <td class="odd">{{el.role}}</td>
      <td class="odd">{{el.email}}</td>
      <td>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>
              <a *ngIf="isAdmin()" class="btn btn-danger" (click)="deleteUser(el.id)">Delete</a>
            </td>
            <td>
              <a *ngIf="isAdmin()" class="btn btn-success" data-original-title="Edit">Edit</a>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: thank's a lot ,it's very helpful

Answer (score 0):

Add this css

```
table td {
    word-break: break-all;
}
```

And use this corrected html. Make sure you header columns and body columns are equals.

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="table-wrap">
        <table class="table table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="odd" colspan="4">id</th>
                    <th class="odd" colspan="4">name</th>
                    <th *ngIf="isAdmin()" class="odd" colspan="4"> password</th>
                    <th class="odd" colspan="4">role</th>
                    <th class="odd" colspan="4">email</th>
                    <th class="odd" colspan="4"></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr *ngFor="let el of users | paginate: { itemsPerPage: 2, currentPage: p }">
                    <td class="odd" colspan="4">{{el.id}} </td>
                    <td class="odd" colspan="4">{{el.username}}</td>
                    <td *ngIf="isAdmin()" class="odd" colspan="4">{{el.password}}</td>
                    <td class="odd" colspan="4">{{el.role}}</td>
                    <td class="odd" colspan="4">{{el.email}}</td>
                    <td>
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <a *ngIf="isAdmin()" class="btn btn-danger" (click)="deleteUser(el.id)">Delete</a>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <a *ngIf="isAdmin()" class="btn btn-success" data-original-title="Edit">Edit</a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it helps me because the table became more clear but still not organized between rows and columns

Comment: if its helpful upvote. Share complete code or stackblitz becuse with current code and image you shared there is not much understanding

Comment: yes it's helpful ,but i didn't get a clear result , i have made an update and i put the image of my result when i add "table td {
    word-break: break-all;
}"   https://i.stack.imgur.com/q1lcW.png
thank's for your answer

Comment: What do you mean by still not organized? How do you want to display table?

Comment: if you see the picture here https://i.stack.imgur.com/q1lcW.png hajer for example should be under the name but it's not  and  as an example hajer@gmail.com under email ...that's what i mean by organized

Comment: @Malék See updated answer